# what situation could cause exist some digit number append main class name(e.g. FooApp(1)) in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I used spring boot to create some project , and run `SomeApplication` class in eclipse.  In `Console` tab exist this kind of message, e.g.
[image]

See above there is `(1)` appended Application class name. I'm curious why have `(1)`.

When I run another spring boot project, it only have Application class name,
[image]

So what situation could cause exist some digit number append main class name in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the name of the 'Run Configuration' for the application - see the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog.

The configuration has been duplicated for some reason, in this case Eclipse adds '(1)' to the configuration name.